# CSS, inject line break after certain number of symbols

Tags: html, css

I have some text inside of a container. The container could be `div`, `td`, or even `p` which may look like this in browser:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

Is it possible to inject linebreaks purely by CSS after certain number of characters. for example if we should inject after 10 symbols it should look like this:

```
Lorem ipsu
m dolor si
t amet, co
nsectetur 
adipiscing
 elit, sed
 do eiusmo
d tempor i
ncididunt 
ut labore 
et dolore 
magna aliq
ua.
```

Is it possible to make this purely by CSS, without any javascript?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. You could set the width of the container and force break after each letters, but it is not line break injection and it would not work with spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to consider a monospace font where the width of all the characters is the same thus you can fix the width of the container based on this width and obtain *visually* what you want:

```css
.box {
  font-family: "Inconsolata", monospace;
  width: 10ch;
  word-break: break-all;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="box">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>
<div class="box" style="font-size:20px;">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>
```

Comment: `ch` uses the width of element `0` in the font used. This works when the font used has all the characters the same width as `0`. So good observation that `ch` works with `monospace`

Answer (score 1):

You can give your container a fixed width and use [`word-break:break-all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break):

```css
.test {
  width: 75px;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would set

```
p, td, div {
word-break: break-all
}
```

and define the width in em units. I don't know if this works exactly as you want, but should help you.

Answer (score -3):

You can't. The most current solution is to set your parent container width in char :

```
div {
 width: 10em;
}
```